# Bisection method - loop break

Tags: c, bisection

Having troubles exiting the while loop once the correct root has been found (value of r3 == 0). Should I be using a break somewhere, if so - where?

I have already tried playing around with the conditional for the if, else if and else statements. Tried placing the break; in different places but couldn't have it in such a way that I still received correct output (mostly it was breaking after the first iteration)

```
float fun(float t);
float fun(float t)
{
    double result; 
    result = (cos(t) - t); //my function
    return result; 
}

void main()
{
    float a; float b; float error; float root;
    scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &error); //scanning for range of bisection and maximum allowed error
int i = 0; 

if (fun(a) == 0)
{
    root = a; 
    printf("The root is : %f", a);
}
else if (fun(b) == 0)
{
    root = b; 
    printf("The root is : %f", b);
}
else 
{
    while (i < 100)
    {
        float r1 = fun(a);
        float r2 = fun(b);
        root = (a+b)/2.0; 
        float r3 = fun(root); 
        printf("The root after %d iteration is %f\n",i,root);
        if(r1*r3 < 0 && r3 != 0) //intermediate value theorem
        {
            b = root;
        }
        else if(r3*r2 < 0 && r3 != 0) //intermediate value theorem
            {
                a = root;
            }
        i++;
        int *p = &i; //not necessary at this moment
    }
}
printf("The approximation to the root is %f",root);
```

The expected result is that the program should end at the first time that r3 == 0 since that would been that the found root using the bisection method is correct. Therefore, the last iteration should be the one with the correct final value for the root...

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, a condition `r1 * r3 < 0` implies that `r3 != 0` (if `r3 == 0` the product is also 0); no need to test it.

Second, floats are very unlikely to be equal to anything, including 0. You should run a loop as long as you are not satisfied with the result. An `error` parameter is there for a reason.

Third, an unfortunate choice of `a` and `b` may never yield you a result: if `fun(a), fun(b), fun((a+b)/2)` all have the same sign, neither `a` nor `b` ever changes.

That said, the correct code should look like

```
    if (fun(a) * fun(b) > 0) {
        bail_out("Root may not exist\n");
    }

    while (b - a > error) /* see note below */ {
        mid = a + (b - a)/2;
        if (fun(a) * fun(mid) > 0) {
            a = mid;
        } else {
            b = mid;
        }
    }
```

Note: The condition above depends on the semantics of error. In certain circumstances `(abs(fun(mid)) > error)` may be preferable.